# string and numeric separation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I did post the phone no from form

```
def update_phone
  if params[:phone]
  #here I want to check weather params[:phone] is number or string 
end
```

I did use `params[:phone].class` it is always showing string class. How I can find whether string or integer?

Comment: This is a serious mess. What is your question? Please 'code' your code. Edit your question immediately before someone flag or close it.

Comment: thanks Roylee can understand what is my probleam?

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby you mostly do not operate on types but on behaviour of variable. If you want to chceck that `params[:phone]` is valid phone number use regexp, i. e.:

```
phone = params[:phone] if params[:phone] =~ /\A\(?\d{3}\)?-?\d{3}-?\d{3}\Z/
```

But even better option is to check this in validators in your model.

Answer (score 0):

edited, thanks for the comment. I figure this works for most common cases. however, this won't work with leading zeros:

```
str = params[:phone]

#it is numeric if the following is true:
str.to_f.to_s == str || str.to_i.to_s == str
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should use some [Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) in your model combined with a regex for phone numbers: depending on your country's phone number system only digits and some formatting characters like `+-./()` and space should be allowed: `+23 (0) 322/242324-12` or `234.1432.123` are both valid numbers.